# What does "proxied" state means for a Hibernate Session

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, proxy, transactions

I came across this line regarding Hibernate Documentation on Jboss site.

```
Because Hibernate can't bind the "current session" to a transaction, 
as it does in a JTA environment, it binds it to the current Java thread
when i do transction demarcation with plain JDBC. 
It is opened when getCurrentSession() is called for the first time, 
but in a "proxied" state that doesn't allow you to do anything except 
start a transaction.
```

So, what exactly does the author mean by ***"proxied state"*** here. And what link they have, if any, to ***proxy objects***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without JTA, the transaction management is done through the commit/rollback methods of a [JDBC Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html).

This means you have to bind one JDBC Connection to the current running Hibernate Session and to the current logical transaction.

Because passing a JDBC Connection to all Hibernate Session methods would be a terrible design solution, you have to use a Thread-local storage instead.

Hibernate has a flexible [CurrentSessionContext](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/spi/CurrentSessionContext.html), offering the following alternatives:

- JTASessionContext
- ManagedSessionContext
- ThreadLocalSessionContext

So if you choose the ThreadLocaSessionContext, then the underlying JDBC connection will be bound to a Thread local storage and make it available to the current Thread running Session.

If you use Spring, you shouldn't rely on the Hibernate TreadLocal context, but use the Spring specific Transaction Management support, which is implemented by:

- SpringJtaSessionContext
- SpringSessionContext

As for the **proxy state**, the Hibernate TreadLocalContext uses a proxy for the Hibernate Session:

```
protected Session wrap(Session session) {
    final TransactionProtectionWrapper wrapper = new TransactionProtectionWrapper( session );
    final Session wrapped = (Session) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            Session.class.getClassLoader(),
            SESSION_PROXY_INTERFACES,
            wrapper
    );
    wrapper.setWrapped( wrapped );
    return wrapped;
}
```

allowing the current Session to **unbind** itself form the TreadLocal storage when the Session.close() method is called.

```
// If close() is called, guarantee unbind()
if ( "close".equals( methodName ) ) {
    unbind( realSession.getSessionFactory() );
}
```